# win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch('powerpoint.application', 1) taking forever to run

Tags: python, win32com

New to win32com. I am trying to open powerpoint, but win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch taking forever to run.

```
import glob, win32com.client, pythoncom

print('import')
pptApp= win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch('powerpoint.application', 1)
print('pptapp')
presentation = pptApp.Presentations.Add()
slide = presentation.Slides.Add(1, 12)
myDiamond = slide.Shapes.AddShape(4, Top=100,Left=100, Width=20, Height=20)
presentation.SaveAs("myPowerPoint",1)
```

Comment: I couldn't replicate any major delay, though I usually don't use the 2nd parameter to EnsureDispatch() ... I struggled to find any documentation on what it might do (it appears as bForDemand=1). If you haven't used win32com with Powerpoint before, gencache will spend a while generating python stub code, but it should only have to do this once: the 2nd time it runs it should be much quicker, as it is on my system.

Comment: Thank you @DS_London. I am not sure why the powerpoint.application can not be loaded from my side. Other applications, like excel.applicaiton, and word one, work OK

Comment: I reinstall everything, it works now